# i got some error about unreachable code in java how to fix it. i use eclipse neon

Tags: java

i have code from github when i re compile i got error here about unreachable code. here my source code. what is unreachable code meaning here ? and how to fix it ?

```
class z implements Runnable
{
    w a;
    final OrderClient b;
    private static final String[] c;
    
    public z(final OrderClient b, final w a) {
        this.b = b;
        this.a = a;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            this.executeTransaction();
        }
        catch (Exception exception) {
            this.b.onProgress(null, ProgressType.Exception, this.a.e, exception);
        }
    }
    
    public Order executeTransaction() throws TimeoutException, ConnectException, InterruptedException {
        final boolean b = Order.b;
        int i = 0;
        final boolean b2 = b;
        while (i < this.b.TradeTimeout) {
            if (this.a.b != null) {
                throw this.a.b;
            }
            if (this.a.d != null) {
                return E.b(this.a.d, 0);
            }
            if (!this.b.QuoteClient.Connected()) {
                throw new ConnectException(new Exception(z.c[1]), this.b.Log);
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1L);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException ex4) {}
            ++i;
            if (b2) {
                break;
            }
        }
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        final String[] c = z.c;
        throw new TimeoutException(sb.append(c[2]).append(this.b.TradeTimeout).append(c[0]).toString(), this.b.Log);
    }
    
    static {
        final String[] c2 = new String[3];
        int n = 0;
        final String s;
        final int length = (s = "7{`&Ty}\u001dt\u000bZ~y}S}\u0007]c6w\u0006c\u0001@p6|\u0001u\r\\7sk\u0016r\u001dZ~y}\u0018Yy3\u0001t\u0018Bn6u\u0001~\u0005\u000edsa\u0005t\u001a\u000e~x3").length();
        int char1 = 3;
        int index = -1;
        Label_0021: {
            break Label_0021;
            do {
                char1 = s.charAt(index);
                ++index;
                final String s2 = s;
                final int beginIndex = index;
                final char[] charArray = s2.substring(beginIndex, beginIndex + char1).toCharArray();
                int length2;
                int n3;
                final int n2 = n3 = (length2 = charArray.length);
                int n4 = 0;
                while (true) {
                    Label_0184: {
                        if (n2 > 1) {
                            break Label_0184;
                        }
                        length2 = (n3 = n4);
                        do {
                            final char c3 = charArray[n3];
                            char c4 = '\0';
                            switch (n4 % 7) {
                                case 0: {
                                    c4 = '\u0017';
                                    break;
                                }
                                case 1: {
                                    c4 = '\u0016';
                                    break;
                                }
                                case 2: {
                                    c4 = '\u0013';
                                    break;
                                }
                                case 3: {
                                    c4 = 's';
                                    break;
                                }
                                case 4: {
                                    c4 = '\u0011';
                                    break;
                                }
                                case 5: {
                                    c4 = 'h';
                                    break;
                                }
                                default: {
                                    c4 = '.';
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                            charArray[length2] = (char)(c3 ^ c4);
                            ++n4;
                        } while (n2 == 0);
                    }
                    if (n2 > n4) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    break;
                }
                c2[n++] = new String(charArray).intern();
            } while ((index += char1) < length);
        }
        c = c2;
    }
}
```

when i try to compile there is an error in the segment. Error because of unreachable code why like that ?

```
 do {
                char1 = s.charAt(index);
                ++index;
                final String s2 = s;
                final int beginIndex = index;
                final char[] charArray = s2.substring(beginIndex, beginIndex + char1).toCharArray();
                int length2;
                int n3;
                final int n2 = n3 = (length2 = charArray.length);
                int n4 = 0;
                while (true) {
                    Label_0184: {
                        if (n2 > 1) {
                            break Label_0184;
                        }
                        length2 = (n3 = n4);
                        do {
                            final char c3 = charArray[n3];
                            char c4 = '\0';
                            switch (n4 % 7) {
                                case 0: {
                                    c4 = '\u0017';
                                    break;
                                }
                                case 1: {
                                    c4 = '\u0016';
                                    break;
                                }
                                case 2: {
                                    c4 = '\u0013';
                                    break;
                                }
                                case 3: {
                                    c4 = 's';
                                    break;
                                }
                                case 4: {
                                    c4 = '\u0011';
                                    break;
                                }
                                case 5: {
                                    c4 = 'h';
                                    break;
                                }
                                default: {
                                    c4 = '.';
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                            charArray[length2] = (char)(c3 ^ c4);
                            ++n4;
                        } while (n2 == 0);
                    }
                    if (n2 > n4) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    break;
                }
                c2[n++] = new String(charArray).intern();
            } while ((index += char1) < length);
        }
        c = c2;
    }
```

i want to know why there is any error like unreachable code like that ?

Comment: There is a break statement right before that segment so it will never be reached. In general, if you find yourself using breaks with labels, you should probably refactor your code (breaking it into more methods, for example).

Answer (score 1):

Unreachable code means you have some code written after a **return** or **throw**  or a **break** statement.

Here you clearly have this before the starting of "do":

```
Label_0021: {
            break Label_0021;
```

You execution flow ends at this break label. So the do block is unreachable.

Comment: Important to note that return/throw/break have to be unconditional for it to be unreachable. If it is `if(condition) break;` it will work just fine.

Comment: Correct @Amongalen . I just thought of explaining about a simple scenario.

Comment: so the do i have must use method right or what ? can anyone explain one by one

Comment: so i create some methods before break or after break for call the code ? @AbhinabaChakraborty

Comment: @yuyukungkung There is no way we can understand what the code is doing. If you need the do logic just remove the break before it.